# Fedex India Shipping Mehod for India is not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, fedex

I've setup fedex shipping method in Magento 2.

I've checked the origin is set to India.
I've also set the Weight configuration of fedex shipping method more than the product.
but still when I checkout and select Country as India It shows:

"This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."

but when I select other country it works perfectly fine.

I've checked an answer which mentioned "Update the wsdl files in Magento/Fedex/Carrier.php file" and add in a PurposeOfShipment 
but I'm unable to understand how to add it.
Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We have worked with Fedex except India, So we have seen, It is working fine.

But This is first time i have Personally checked for shipment in India, It shows an Error such as

**"This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."**

I also searched in Fedex Blogs and many places, but i found many of developers facing the same issue here. For ex: You can check on this link - [Click Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249045/magento-fedex-shipping-methods-displaying-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-th)

For Conclusion we have check that, this error message we got from the API of Fedex, It means Fedex Currently doesnot support to India Shipment or there are bug in Fedex response.