# Magento Fedex shipping methods displaying “Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time”

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, fedex

I'm using Magento **version 2.2.5**. I am having this problem when checkout, it keeps displaying

> "Sorry, no quotes available for this order at this time"

in **Fedex** shipping method.

When we select country India it show - Sorry, no quotes available for this order at this time.I entered the right address, right zip-code and also the right country.

I used **test credentials** of **FedEx** account [image]

Select other countrey like - Australia work fedex and Flat rate shipping
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your country is enabled in the settings.

Navigate to **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> FedEx**

Make sure India is allowed under "Ship to Specific Countries" list. Alternatively, under "Ship to Applicable Countries" select "All allowed countries".

*In addition, please make sure that the India is allowed under **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Country options***

Comment: I select India both options but show same error - Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time

Comment: Did you flush the cache and reindex?

Comment: yes flush cache and reindex

Comment: If the shipping method is working for Australia and you are sure the country is enabled in configuration then I am pretty sure that there is something wrong with the address itself. Please try a different address, make sure the post/zip code is correct.